# Disable Mac OS X keybinds in java

Tags: java, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to create an application, and I want to remove all the basic mac keybinds. For example, if the user tries to do command+space, then I don't want spotlight to open. How would I go about doing this? Is there something that Toolkit has that I am missing?

Thank you,
Howard Stark

Comment: Man, that would piss me off so much.

Comment: @DaveNewton what would piss you off? Not being able to open spotlight?

Comment: An application turning off my key bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I'm aware of to do this on OS X -- in general, not just in Java -- is to enable kiosk mode by setting `NSApplication.presentationOptions`. I'm not certain that there's any way to do this with Java without delving into JNI, though.

Answer (score -1):

search for keyboard shortcuts in either preferences or spotlight and turn off the ones you dont need